# Import existing Postgre database with phpPgAdmin and double single quotes

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

New to postgre here.

I need to restore a postgre database from a SQL script that has been given to me.

The beginning of the script is:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
/*!40101 SET NAMES  */
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */

-- Listage de la structure de la table public. agreements
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "agreements" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "nextval('agreements_id_seq'::regclass)",
    "text" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT 'NULL::timestamp without time zone',
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT 'NULL::timestamp without time zone',
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

When I try to import this script using phpPgAdmin (PostgreSQL 9.6.22, phpPgAdmin 7.13.0, PHP 8.1.27), I am getting the following error:

```
ERREUR: syntaxe en entrée invalide pour l'entier : « nextval('agreements_id_seq'::regclass) »
```

Meaning that there is an invalid input for the number nextval.

I don't understand what's going on, I already removed from the file semicolons that were at the end of the first commented lines that prevented the import too.

Did the person who create the SQL export chose a wrong format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [nextval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html) is without the *double quotes*.

Additionally you'll need to remove the single quotes in the *timestamp* default.

This works tested in 16.1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "agreements" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT  nextval('agreements_id_seq'::regclass),
    "text" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT  NULL::timestamp without time zone ,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT  NULL::timestamp without time zone ,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was indeed one of the problems but I still getting others like : "db-16-11-2023_v3.sql:14: ERROR: the relationship « agreements_id_seq » does not exist". Does it mean that the person forgot to provide the sequences ?

Comment: Yes, you must create the sequence in advance.